# AWS personalize: filtering all items already interacted with does not seem to persist

Tags: amazon-web-services, filtering, amazon-personalize

We're using AWS Personalize to get a personalized ranking of various items in our feed for a specific user.

We are also using a filter that looks like

```
EXCLUDE ItemID WHERE Interactions.event_type IN ("*")
```

This filter is taken from an [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/introducing-recommendation-filters-in-amazon-personalize/) that states

```
To remove all items that a user has previously interacted with, use the following filter expression:

EXCLUDE itemId WHERE INTERACTIONS.event_type in ("*")
```

Now playing with the console https://console.aws.amazon.com/personalize/home?region=us-east-1#arn:aws:personalize:us-east-1::dataset-group$<dataset_name>/campaigns/campaignDetail/<campaign_arn>

I input a `userId=5253ffbb-f5e3-4e71-9a33-91ee65365c7d` and a bunch of item ids:

```
5829, 5480, 2275, 6706, 5438, 6444, 6444, 7461, 7599, 4384, 6747, 7499, 6491, 5453, 7605, 5985, 6663, 7174, 1094, 6474, 7357, 7220, 8370, 7445, 5721, 991, 5592, 9283, 7547, 8676, 8872, 8092, 9401, 8645, 2090, 7684, 3788, 5849, 6524, 8480, 7299, 5752, 8007, 9100, 7422, 8640, 7917, 9254, 10050, 9851, 1744, 4227, 6388, 9490, 6481, 5744, 6486, 9040, 4048, 8170, 9623, 7966, 8560, 5336, 3885, 4441, 10442, 6842, 4898, 567, 4214, 125, 9556, 10039, 5494, 9447, 10051, 8302, 9482, 6649, 9133, 4828, 8288, 62, 9680, 4792, 10785, 9727, 10777, 11366, 10252, 9728, 2450, 10463, 9578, 4246, 10154, 10793, 10299, 6733, 10597, vy7erddv, 9247, 9816, 8385, 9589, 10845, 10368, 11427, 11405, 10475, 11273, 11392, 11335, 5871, 10465, 10927, 9371, 9894, 10773, 10747, 11274, 11349, 10831, 9882, vaxq362m, m3g32ayv, 5wqa8r4v, km7kl7kv, 3wno92pm, 3m483l5v, pv9rallv, lmr4dn8v
```

Now I log interactions of this user with some items and reload the console recommendations...

This *appears* to work as expected and the items get filtered from the list if the user already interacted with them.

BUT to my surprise...these items DO NOT remain filtered indefinitely...If I continue logging interactions against other items for this user, then later re-loads of recommendations might feature items that were previously interacted with. Or given enough time (like a day) all of the items seem to just come back for this user!!

I'm totally lost as to figure out why it is behaving like this.

The interactions get tracked as

```
POST https://personalize-events.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/events
{
   "eventList": [ 
      { 
         "eventType": "list_view",
         "ITEM_ID": "vaxq362m",
         "properties": "{\"itemType\": \"artwork\", \"itemId\": \"vaxq362m\"}",
         "sentAt": {{$timestamp}}
      }
   ],
   "sessionId": "xxx1234",
   "trackingId": "<OUR_TRACKING_ID>",
   "userId": "5253ffbb-f5e3-4e71-9a33-91ee65365c7d"
}
```

And this seems to work because

1. The status of the response is 200
2. The interaction appears in the CSV if I export the interactions dataset
3. The items DO get removed INITIALLY for a short time from the recommendations that come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering on the interactions dataset does not take the full history for the user into account. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/filter-expressions.html):

> Amazon Personalize considers up to 200 historical interactions for a user, and up to 100 streamed interactions you record for the user with the PutEvents operation. Additionally, the number of historical interactions Amazon Personalize considers for a user depends on the max_user_history_length_percentile and min_user_history_length_percentile hyperparameters you defined before training.

> For example, if you used .99 for the max_user_history_length_percentile, and 99% of your users have at most 4 interactions, Amazon Personalize will only filter based on the user's most recent 4 historical interactions. If a user has less than the number historical interactions at the min_user_history_length_percentile, Amazon Personalize doesn't consider the user's interactions when filtering.

> To filter based on up to 200 historical interactions for a user, set the max_user_history_length_percentile to 1.0 and retrain the model.

Comment: Damn, that's a blow. But thanks for the response.